# Rebus OneWayClient create queue if not exists

Tags: rebus

I'm having an error sending messages (not publishing) with rebus when configured as one way client (RabbitMq and Azure) because the queues must exists.

Is there a way with OneWayClient to create queues if not exists before sending messages?

Answer (score 7):

Rebus' RabbitMQ transport intentionally doesn't create destination queues if they do not exist – instead, it throws an exception.

This way, its behavior aligns with other transports like MSMQ, Azure Service Bus, Amazon SQS, etc., since they all throw an exception if you accidentally send to a non-existent queue.

The reasoning behind this behavior, is that it's almost always an error, if you send to a queue that doesn't exist – because, when you send a message to a queue, it's a sign that you care about the message, and you care that a special someone is going to have it, but if that special someone doesn't exist, you most likely want to know it as fast as possible.